# Error when trying to run composer install in a Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I try to run `composer install` to install the dependencies in a Laravel 5 project, but I got this error:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.3.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.3.4].
    - intervention/image 2.3.4 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
```

I've heard some folks say about adding something in my `PHP.ini` file, but I don't know which `PHP.ini` should be configured, since I have 2 `PHP.ini` files, 1 in XAMPP and 1 in IISEXPRESS. I don't know how to solve this problem, please any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the %PATH% variable. in the command prompt type `echo %PATH%`

Comment: "the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system" First thing I'd try is installing that extension.

Comment: how to install that extension?

Answer (score 1):

I moved my composer and started getting the same error. So I removed PHP7.0 and install 7.1 and it fixed that issue. I'm almost certain that I could have run the below command for 7.0 and it would have solved the issue too.

**7.1**

```
sudo apt install -y php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-bz2 php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-tidy php7.1-mbstring php-redis php-memcached
```

**7.0**

```
sudo apt install -y php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip php7.0-fpm php7.0-bz2 php7.0-json php7.0-tidy php-redis  php-memcached
```